# I can access my website from any vpn but LetsEncrypt show my website is down I have followed all other articles. How can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, web, https, dns

My website, nclicker.mooo.com:443 on 94.193.235.194 is accessible but LetsEncrypt tell me it is down or I can't connect to it. I am running a node js/express server on it and am trying to get a https certificate with LetsEncrypt. I have put a firewall on it for now but the same happens when the firewall is disabled.

Comment: Why are you using plain http instead of https?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I dont have a certificate and LetsEncrypt is trying to serve me one but every service including LetsEncrypt and downforeveryoneorjustme tells me its down when it isnt and I have tried on multiple vpns

Comment: I forgot to mention port 80 is in use by another service